# How to make this sentence sound formal? (Not asking for proofreading!)

Tags: expressions

Say a girl who had spent six years in the U.S. and just went back to her home country. Because she spoke English for most of the time in the US, it takes a while for her to adapt to a new environment where English is not the most commonly used language.

> I can see how hard she tried to not speak in English whenever she took a long pause during the speech.

Here's what came right off my dome when I first decided to make it sound more like things that a psycholinguist would write in his notepad.

> I can see her efforts to resist the urge to speak in English whenever she paused during the speech.

Is there any more formal or academic way to convey the meaning here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about "She made a long pause in the middle of her speech and I could see her fighting the urge to let the English she had become so familiar to slip out from between her lips." or you could change it to "She made a long pause in the middle of her speech and I could see her fighting the urge to let English escape from her lips." to take out the part of English being so familiar to her know if it's excessive or just supposed to be implied.

You could also consider writing it as, "While making her speech she paused for a while and I could see her fighting the to let English escape from her lips." just depending on how you want to start the sentence off. Also, you can see I wrote some sentences with "escape from her lips" and another with "slip out from between her lips" because I thought they would both work nicely and I figured you could just pick the option that works best for what you're writing.